# Visibility of polygons from an edge

Tags: visibility, polygon, computational-geometry

Given is a 2D are with the polygons. I need to find out the polygons visible in a perpendicular line of sight from the a given line segment lying within that area. e.g.

[image: A sample example of the problem]

- Further,

  What can be the optimizations when the polygons have only vertical and horizontal edges.

Comment: Are the line segments always either all the way to the left of all polygons (or to the right of them)? Or can the segments also be in the middle of your polygons?

Comment: They can be in middle. In that case that polygon should be reported as a separate result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest the following ...

- Rotate the problem so your 'line of sight' segment is aligned to the x axis.
- Find the (axis aligned) bounding rectangle (BR) of each polygon.
- Sort the polygons using the Y coordinate of the bottom edge of each BR
- Create a clipping 'range buffer' to mark the portions of the viewing segment that will be no longer visible.
- For each polygon C (current) in the sorted list do ...

  1. Use C's left and right bounds as its initial clipping range.
  2. Trim C's clipping range with the range already marked as clipped in the 'range buffer'.
  3. Now for each subsequent polygon S of a similar depth (ie where S's BR bottom edge starts below C's BR top edge) ...

     - loop to next S if it doesn't overlap horizontally with C
     - determine if S is overlapping from the left or right (eg by comparing the BR horizontal midpoints of S and C). If S overlaps from the right and S's left-most vertex is below C's right-most vertex, then truncate C's clipping range accordingly. (Likewise if S overlaps from the left.)
  4. If the residual clipping range isn't empty, then at least part of C is visible from your viewing segment. Now add C's residual clipping range to the clipping 'range buffer'.

Comment: Thanks Angus, this is very much what I was looking for.

Comment: I should also mention that the algorithm above would only safely work with convex polygons. Concave polygons would have to be split into convex polygons before applying the algorithm.