# Polygon Clipping: Only "viewable" area

Tags: algorithm, math, polygon, computational-geometry, clipping

In the image below you see in (1) a triangle and a circle. Given a dedicated point X in that triangle I want clip away everything that is not visible from this point. There's no problem with removing just the circle with a simple polygon difference algorithm like in (2). But what kind of algorithm can I use to get a polygon like in (3) ?

The Polygon is always simple.

Edit: The circle is just an example. Every simple polygon should be possible.

[image: Image #1]

You can image my needs by taking a look at the image of the game "Commandos - Behind enemy lines":

[image: Image #2]

Comment: +1, Commandos. Excellent game.

Comment: If you don't get an answer, you might offer a bounty.

Comment: Your question seems very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/5892539/359538

Comment: @Angus: It looks like a completely different problem to me. Just a simple scan-line algorithm with a check for line intersection. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @tur1ng a simple circular scan will do also in your case, but it will be greatly inefficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the basic idea.

I'm assuming a problem a few more general, but it will be a lot easier to adapt it to your problem: given a `plan` containing all the shapes, a point and a set of geometrical shapes, we want to remove from the plan the area not visible from that point.

What we want to do is to get, for each shape, it's `starting_polar` and `ending_polar` points, that are the 2 points with the minimum and maximum polar angle belonging to the shape.

Now we'll remove from the `plan` the shape and we'll remove the `quadrilateral` formed by the points: `starting_polar`, `ending_polar`, and the intersections between the 2 straight lines `(x, starting_polar)` and `(x, ending_polar)` and the boundaries of the `plan`.

In your case the plan will simply be the `triangle`.

Comment: Sound promising I'll give it a try.

Comment: it will work for sure for convex shapes; but i think that if a shape is concave and you can divide it in convex subshapes this will still work repeating it for all the subshapes of the shape

Answer (score 0):

C parallel to D, G parallel to A, B parallel to F, D is diameter.

[image: Polygon]

Comment: Sorry but I forgot to mention that the circle is just an example. Every simple polygon should be possible.

Comment: Nope, anyway Simone answer provide better solution for any case:)

Comment: For any case in which the shape in convex..if is concave it doesn't always work perfectly...but i suspect that if we can subdivide each concave shape in convex shape then the problem is solvable for concave shapes too

Comment: Correct, [here](http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0201/algorithm_0201.htm) is nice examples for convex shape.